# Print multiple barcode images

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, barcode

I have created the windows application to generate bar-code.

I am generating multiple bar-code images and saving them in a folder now i want to display all of them in the picture box and print them help..

Comment: Where is the problem?? How to load an image into the PictureBox? Or more than one? Or how to print something? For the latter two: Use e.Graphics.DrawImage(...) in the Paint or in the PrintPage events!

Comment: I am not able to load all bar-code images I've generated into picture box.

Comment: A PictureBox can only hold one image in its Image. You can easily draw more images on its surface. But you need to know the sizes they have. - Also: You should probably not print the content of anything you display because the display and the printer have usually very different resolutions. Therefore you should code both the Paint and the PrintPage event. Please edit your question to include these data: number and layout of the images, size of the images and picturebox(in pixels), printerresolution (in dpi) !

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically create the picture box and add to form.

See the sample code:

```
private void LoadPic()
{
    string path = @"Path here";

    PictureBox pic;
    FlowLayoutPanel panel;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    foreach ( string item in Directory.GetFiles ( path ) )
    {
        pic = new PictureBox ();
        panel = new FlowLayoutPanel ();
        panel.Location = new Point ( x, y );
        pic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (100, 100 );
        pic.ImageLocation =  item;
        panel.Controls.Add ( pic );
        pic.Click +=pic_Click;
        panel1.Controls.Add ( panel );

        y = y + 100;


    }



}
```